# How do I get the n last letters in a string

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of strings in javascript which hold dates such as "2015-02-17", how can I get the n last characters of that string as a substring like "02-17" or "17" ?

Comment: well, that's a quite basic thing. Did you try something? there is a very large amount of possible solutions for such a case, you can either use regular expressions or simply consider the string an array... Or substring.. Well..

Comment: I've tried slice and grabbing by index numbers, i'm looking for a clean solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) method:

```
var x = '2015-02-17';
var last2Characters = x.substring(x.length - 2);
```

or [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) with a negative number:

```
var last2Characters = x.slice(-2);
```

Comment: why not slice(-2) directly

Comment: Yeah slice would definitely work nice as well. Thanks for spotting on this.

Comment: coming from a java background, things like str.slice(-2) don't come naturally